# opencv perspectiveTransform produces incorrect transformation despite good homography inliers

Tags: java, opencv

I am having a problem trying to get perspectiveTransform() to produce results I can make sense of.

I am writing an image matching application. Most of these images are paintings. What I am matching is whole-whole, whole-part, part-whole or even part-part. The resolutions will be different. Because of this relationship the "object" "scene" terminology typically used doesn't fit. Because the object can in fact be the scene and vice versa. So I use query image and target indexed image to describe the query and the image I'm matching against.

I have been following various OpenCV tutorials on matching one image to another and then using the perspectiveTransform to be able to place a bounding box on the identified image...but Im running into problems.

[Image 1 - Whole-Part - Result of image matching: The query image (left), target pre-indexed img (right)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVtZq.jpg)

In the image added to this we can see I have a whole-part relationship. 
The images have been scaled to max edge 1000 and turned to greyscale as part of the SIFT process which has proceeded this.

```
Query image dimensions x=1000, y=750  
Idx image dimensions x=667, y=1000  

Initial Flann matches: 501  
After Lowe's 2nd nn ratio: 48 matches  
RANSAC inliers: 37 matches
```

The code..

```
homography = Calib3d.findHomography(idxMatOfPoint2f, queryMatOfPoint2f, Calib3d.RANSAC, 5, mask, 2000, 0.995);
Mat query_corners = new Mat(4, 1, CvType.CV_32FC2);
Mat idx_corners = new Mat(4, 1, CvType.CV_32FC2);


query_corners.put(0, 0, new double[]{0, 0});
query_corners.put(1, 0, new double[]{queryImage.cols() - 1, 0});
query_corners.put(2, 0, new double[]{queryImage.cols() - 1, queryImage.rows() - 1});
query_corners.put(3, 0, new double[]{0, queryImage.rows() - 1});

Core.perspectiveTransform(query_corners, idx_corners, homography);
```

The result of this code gives the following data (original x,y : transformed x,y )

```
Corners - Top-left  = 0.0,0.0 : 163.84683227539062,167.56898498535156  
Corners - Top-right = 999.0,0.0 : 478.38623046875,169.61349487304688  
Corners - Bot-right  = 999.0,749.0 : 491.45220947265625,411.24688720703125  
Corners - Bot-left  = 0.0,749.0 : 162.11233520507812,411.5089416503906
```

Now clearly the points are drawn image are wrong - but selecting which to draw on means I have already determined this. However, what I find odd is that the box is the entire size of the query image, transformed into the space of the 2nd image. I wasnt expecting the box to reduce in size and shape in a way that doesnt even seem to match the first image.

The transformed x,y just do not make any sense to me. Can anyone shed any light on this please?

[Image 2 - Part-Whole - Result of image matching: The query image (left), target pre-indexed img (right)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLFUj.jpg)

Looking at image 2 where the query is a part and the whole the target idx image gives:

```
Initial Flann matches: 500
After Lowe's 2nd nn ratio: 21
RANSAC inliers: 17

query image dimensions x=1000, y=750
idx   image dimensions x=1000, y=609

Corners - Top-left  = 0.0,0.0 : -1228.55224609375,-923.1514282226562
Corners - Top-right = 999.0,0.0 : 3561.064453125,-930.8649291992188
Corners - Bot-right  = 999.0,749.0 : 2768.0224609375,1934.417236328125
Corners - Bot-left  = 0.0,749.0 : -699.1375732421875,2089.652587890625
```

Again this just makes absolutely no sense to me. -1228? But both images are only 1000 across and the query is wholly contained in the target idx image.

This last image shows the frustration in this. 
[Image 3 - Whole-Whole](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4paiF.jpg)
Here we can see perspective transformed corners are just way-off - its actually smaller than the image being matched to...It seems the perspective transformation function is returning almost random results.

Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong? Am I mis-understanding the perspective transformation?

Comment: can you try homography = Calib3d.findHomography(queryMatOfPoint2f, idxMatOfPoint2f, Calib3d.RANSAC, 5, mask, 2000, 0.995);? (different order of query/idx)

Comment: aha. Good point. Odd that I have it that way round - Ill try the other way round.

Comment: not sure which ordering is right, but that's a common error source :D

Comment: i can see why this would affect the points returned later. 
A quick try led to allowing large numbers of unmatched items through.
One issue is that where you have multiple points in the query object that map to a single point. Images of postage stamps or with words such as illuminated MS can result in these sorts of matches - which is what Im trying to eliminate via homography...
I shall go through the sets of points Im using carefully and make sure Im not swapping something. Pity I cant add images to comments - so Ill update the main question if this doesn't solve my issue. Thanks.

Comment: Yep that has solved the box issue. 
However Im getting issues with the quality of the matches now - the homography in the query->idx includes spurious matches but when the images do relate it gets the right bounding bow.
Ill post another question regarding the matching issue.

Thanks very much for spotting such a simple error!
(mind you the reverse homography check actually solves the spurious match issue! Although that may not be the best method.)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Micka...The answer for the issue in the perspectiveTransform() is because the query and pre-indexed image points were swapped over in the function call. The following call gives the correct result for a matched image.

homography = Calib3d.findHomography(queryMatOfPoint2f, idxMatOfPoint2f, Calib3d.RANSAC, 5, mask, 2000, 0.995);

However, the homography is letting through a curious set of matches which shouldn't be allowed.
Ill post a new Q as the perspective transform is now solved.